# ansible.builtin.file is using user from wrong host

Tags: ansible

I have this playbook below to set user/group on the user's home directory.

`jimbo` and `bobo` here have different UID and GIDs on the different boxes.

Running this script will set the UID/GID ownership of the directories incorrectly.

For example, it will set `/home/jimbo` on `operatorbox1` (1) to be owned by the UID of `jimbo` from `operatorbox2` (2) - which is of course not the correct UID on `operatorbox1` (1).

It does this seemingly randomly.  If I run this playbook multiple times the ownership of the directories will flip back and forth.

Guessing I have something fundamental missing here. Why is this happening? Thanks!

ansible-playbook v2.9.23

**./vars/operators.yml**

```yaml
---
  operators:
    jimbo: sshekeywhatever
    bobo: sshkeywhatever
```

**playbook.yml**

```yaml
---
- name: Setup operators
  hosts:
    - bastionbox
    - operatorbox
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - "./vars/operators.yml"

  tasks:
    - name: Set home directory permissions
      file:
        path: "/home/{{ item.key }}"
        state: directory
        owner: "{{ item.key }}"
        group: "{{ item.key }}"
        recurse: true
      with_dict:
        - "{{ operators }}"
```

Comment: So you want to do that only when the user exists on the remote host?

Comment: Maybe output of `ls -l /home` after first, second, third run could be relevant

Comment: the users are known to exist on all remote hosts

Comment: You say: *"`it will set /home/jimbo on operatorbox1 to be owned by the UID of jimbo from operatorbox2`"*. I don't see any reason why this should happen. But, it's up to you to provide [mre] including the relevant part  of */etc/passwd* and *'ls -ln /home'*. In addition to this, none of `operatorbox1` and `operatorbox2` is mentioned in the code.

Comment: Since your `hosts:` seems to reference a group called `operatorbox` which might contain a list `['operatorbox1', 'operatorbox2']`, can you confirm my guess with your `inventory`? What is contained in `/vars/operators.yml`?

Comment: In terms of [mre]: 1) get rid of the file `vars/operators.yml` 2) Put the list into the *vars*   `operators: [jimbo, bobo]` 3) replace `with_dict` with `loop: "{{ operators }}"` and 4) replace `{{ item.key }}` with `{{ item }}`

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem. Below is a playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: bastionbox,operatorbox
  gather_facts: false
  become: true

  vars:

    operators: [jimbo, bobo]

  tasks:

    - name: Create users
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
        uid: "{{ range(2500, 2600)|random }}"
      loop: "{{ operators }}"
      when: create_users|d(false)|bool

    - name: List users uid
      block:
        - getent:
            database: passwd
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ item }} uid: {{ getent_passwd[item].1 }}"
          loop: "{{ operators }}"
      when: list_users|d(false)|bool

    - name: Set home directory owner and group
      file:
        state: directory
        path: "/home/{{ item }}"
        owner: "{{ item }}"
        group: "{{ item }}"
        recurse: true
      loop: "{{ operators }}"
      when: set_homes|d(false)|bool

    - name: List homes
      block:
        - find:
            paths: /home
            file_type: directory
            patterns: "{{ operators }}"
          register: out
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ item.path }} uid: {{ item.uid }}"
          loop: "{{ out.files }}"
          loop_control:
            label: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      when: list_homes|d(false)|bool

    - name: Delete users
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
        remove: true
      loop: "{{ operators }}"
      when: delete_users|d(false)|bool
```

---

- Create users

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook -e create_users=true pb.yml
```

- List users

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook -e list_users=true pb.yml
```

```yaml
  msg: 'bastionbox jimbo uid: 2572'
  msg: 'operatorbox jimbo uid: 2537'
  msg: 'bastionbox bobo uid: 2505'
  msg: 'operatorbox bobo uid: 2557'
```

- List homes

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook -e list_homes=true pb.yml
```

```yaml
  msg: 'bastionbox /home/bobo uid: 2505'
  msg: 'operatorbox /home/jimbo uid: 2537'
  msg: 'bastionbox /home/jimbo uid: 2572'
  msg: 'operatorbox /home/bobo uid: 2557'
```

- Set homes (task is idempotent)

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook -e set_homes=true pb.yml
```

```yaml
TASK [Set home directory owner and group] *************************
ok: [operatorbox] => (item=jimbo)
ok: [bastionbox] => (item=jimbo)
ok: [operatorbox] => (item=bobo)
ok: [bastionbox] => (item=bobo)
```